# How do I test a value against multiple lists nested in a dict

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to test if my string appears in multiple lists nested in a dict...

```
if value1 in any[myDict['nested1']['list1'], myDict['nested2']['list2']]:
```

this is what i'm trying to do, but I can't seem to make it work
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list or tuple with all the items you may want to check, then using `in` you can check if `value1` is inside it:

```
if value1 in (*myDict['nested1']['list1'], *myDict['nested2']['list2']):
```

Comment: thanks, it was the * that I was missing.
I've never used an * in a list like that before, but it works.
I assume the * tells it to construct everything after it as a single item within the list.

Comment: @ProgD it's called `unpacking`, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is the same as `[*[1, 2, 3], *[4, 5, 6]]`. Basically, that line disarms the list throwing its items in the next "container" which in this case it's a list (and so it makes a new list with those items). This works even in functions like you can see in `print(*[1, 2, 3])`. Even more, you can *unpack* dictionaries using `**`. `{1: 2, 3: 4}` is the same as `{**{1: 2}, **{3: 4}}`